# Non Case sensitive in ORM search method in openerp

Tags: database, orm, odoo

I have problem with non-case-sensitive in **ORM** method in **OpenERP**. I search the duplicate rows in the database as follow:

```
    duplicate_ids = sns_obj.search(cr, uid, [('country_id', '=', country_id),
('keyword_list', '=', final_str), ('origin', '=', origin)])
```

How can I search in the database without caring about the **case-sensitive**

```
Ex: in Country_ID, "Vietnam" = "vietnam" or something like that
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution to your problem is operator **ilike**

```
duplicate_ids = sns_obj.search(cr, uid, [('country_id', 'ilike', country_id),
('keyword_list', 'ilike', final_str), ('origin', 'ilike', origin)])
```